# CORS: write and read a cookie through two website and client/server languages (javascript and ASP.NET C#)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, cookies, cross-domain

i have two web site:

1. www.foo.com
2. www.bar.com

on `www.bar.com/page.aspx` i set a session cookie with name "baz" and after redirect to `www.foo.com/page2.aspx`:

```
// set the "baz" cookie 
Response.Cookies["baz"].Value   = "test";
Response.Cookies["baz"].HttpOnly = false;

// redirect to www.foo.com/page2.aspx
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://www.foo.com/page2.aspx");
```

on `www.foo.com/page2.aspx` i include a javascript from `www.bar.com`, eg:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//www.bar.com/script.js"></script>
...
```

`script.js` make an ajax request to `www.bar.com/ajax.aspx` (same server):

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", 'http://www.bar.com/ajax.aspx', true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

and `ajax.aspx` try to read "baz" cookie

```
string cookie = Request.Cookies["baz"].Value
```

but "baz" cookie is `null`!

if i open `www.bar.com/ajax.aspx` into browser the cookie is read correctly.

it's a CORS problem? how solve it?

Comment: try to add `xmlhttp.withCredentials = true` is a Boolean that indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials such as cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, this is browser security which is preventing the server from getting the Cookie from a different site.  What you can do to work around this issue is to pass the cookie from bar to foo via the query string:

```
// redirect to www.foo.com/page2.aspx
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://www.foo.com/page2.aspx?baz=test");
```

And then get the value as so:

```
string cookie = Request.QueryString["baz"];
```

Comment: the problem seem not read the cookie on www.foo.com, but read the cookie on www.bar.com in an ajax request... maybe the browser not send the cookie in an ajax request also if the recipient website of the request is the cookie's owner.